# Base constructor not being called/resolved properly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, constructor, overriding

**Background info:**

I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 for this project. I want to use a class, System.IO.DirectoryInfo, to get a directory listing. However, the implementation of GetDirectories() doesn't work for me, since upon throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException exception, the function fails.

I would like to create a DLL that defines a derived class having the same functionality of the DirectoryInfo class, but overrides GetDirectories() so I can have the functionality I need.

**The problem:**

I must be doing something wrong when trying to call the base constructor. I get the error "'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments".

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CompanyName.System.IO
{
    public class FlexibleDirectoryInfo : DirectoryInfo
    {
        public FlexibleDirectoryInfo(string path) : base(path) {}
        [...]
```

DirectoryInfo does not have a default constructor, and instead has a single constructor taking a string parameter, just like I'm trying to do. However, I'm not sure if it's resolving the base constructor properly?

I have a feeling this is a simple fix. Please just help point out what I'm overlooking. :)

Thanks!

Comment: `DirectoryInfo` is marked as `sealed`, so you *can't* inherit from it. If you're getting an `UnauthorizedAccessException`, then figure out how to get authorized!

Comment: @dlev The directory in question that threw the exception was C:\Documents and Settings. I could probably figure out how to elevate privileges for the program, but I would think that it wouldn't be keeping to the principle of least privilege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DirectoryInfo` is a sealed class. So you cannot derive from it.
From MSDN:

> public **sealed** class DirectoryInfo : FileSystemInfo

However, you create a class that inherits [FileSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx) (superclass for `DirectoryInfo`). You'll have to create most of the implementation, but it's the only way.

Comment: Darn, didn't notice that when I was reading the documentation. Guess that explains a lot. Thanks!